# Exclude Tags Based on Content in Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping html data that is similar to the following:

```
<div class="target-content">
    <p id="random1">
      "the content of the p"
    </p>

    <p id="random2">
      "the content of the p"
    </p>

    <p>
      <q class="semi-predictable">
         "q tag content that I don't want
      </q>
    </p>

    <p id="random3">
      "the content of the p"
    </p>

</div>
```

My goal is to get all the `<p>` tags, along with their content—while being able to exclude the `<q>` tag, along with it's content. Currently, I getting all the `<p>` tags with the following approach:

```
contentlist = soup.find('div', class_='target-content').find_all('p')
```

My question, is after I find the result set of all the `<p>` tags, how can I filter out the single `<p>`, along with it's content, that contains the `<q>`?

Of Note: after getting the results set from `soup.find('div', class_='target-content')find_all('p')`, I am iteratively adding each `<p>` from the result set to a list in the following manner:

```
content = ''
    for p in contentlist:
        content += str(p)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just skip `p` tags having the `q` tag inside:

```
for p in soup.select('div.target-content > p'):
    if p.q:  # if q is present - skip
        continue
    print(p)
```

where `p.q` is a shortcut to `p.find("q")`. `div.target-content > p` is a [CSS selector](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) which would match all `p` tags that are direct children of `div` element with `target-content` class.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I trying to understand. Thank you as well for the explanation; I don't think to use CSS Selectors as often as I should with Beautifulsoup.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `filter` to accomplish this:

```
filter(lambda e: e.find('q') == None, soup.find('div', class_='target-content').find_all('p'))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I ended up using a variation of @alexce 's answer above, although yours proved useful as well.