# How to use Beautiful Soup to select a specific span with a lot of childs?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Exception has occurred: NotImplementedError
':exclude' pseudo-class is not implemented at this time

I'm trying to webscrape a site but I keep getting the NotImplementedError when I'm executing this code down below. I'm assuming this is not working because BeautifulSoup does not have ':exclude'. The path down below is what I copied using the chrome browser.

```
soup.select('#objectWrapper8229 > wissearch:exclude > div:nth-child(1) > div.wp3-portlet-content > div > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(6) > td:nth-child(3) > span > a > span'
```

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, after some research it seems that beautifulSoup does not have the exclude selector implemented.
Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38058262/exclude-tags-based-on-content-in-beautifulsoup) post can help you with your exclusion issue.